# Using Python and os.walk to find targets

Tags: python, directory, os.walk, python-os

I am currently working on a script to sift through filesystems (both Linux and Windows), to search for specific strings in text files. With what I have below I can select where I want to start, get the full paths to the files with the extensions I want, but the stringstofind does not seem to iterate correctly. I will eventually make this to where I can select the file extensions to search, and enter what strings I am looking for, but for now, I just need this to work so I can understand what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance!

so far I have:

```
import os

userinput = input("What directory to search?")
stringstofind = ["String1", "String2", "String3"]
for roots,subdir, files in os.walk(userinput):
   for fname in files:
      #I know this if line is ugly, but like with stringstofind I had a hard 
      #time getting it to iterate through right.
      if ".txt" in fname or ".rtf" in fname or ".doc" in fname:
         filepath = os.path.join(roots,fname)
         with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
            for lines in f:
               if stringstofind in lines:
                  print("found target")
```

Comment: This actually should produce an **error**, and if so, then you should [edit] your question so that it contains the actual error message in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a bit of a type mismatch:

- every `lines` variable produced by `for lines in f:` loop is actually a string
- `stringstofind` is defined as a list

You are trying to do `if stringstofind in lines:` checking if a list of strings is inside a string.

---

What you probably meant was to check if any of the strings defined in the `stringstofind` list is a part of a line. You could use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) for that:

```
for line in f:
   if any(item in line for item in stringstofind):
      print("found target")
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
if stringstofind in lines:
    print("found target")
```

use:

```
for string in stringstofind:
    if string in lines:
        print("found target")
```